# What is the name of the design pattern used in method chaining in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, design-patterns, method-chaining

What is the name of the design pattern behind method chaining in jQuery?

Example: `$( "p" ).css( "color", "red" ).find( ".special" ).css( "color", "green" );`

Comment: What are you actually asking?  Any method call that returns an object can do method chaining.  Not much more to it than that.

Comment: I am asking ,what is the name of the design pattern behind that method chaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/137999/what-is-the-pattern-name-for-using-method-chaining-to-build-an-object, it's called a **Fluent Interface**.

I see many articles referring to it simply as **method chaining** also (which seems more descriptive) and also the **Chaining Pattern**.  It seems the more you search, the more different names you can find, though there are many references to the term "fluent interface".